# Weights in multi-level models

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, weights

I really hope that this is the right place to ask my question and that it hasn't been asked yet - otherwise please let me know.

I am currently running a multi-level regression model with a cross-level interaction (the model concerns the interaction effect of personality and contextual direct democracy on political interest in the United States).

The data I am using for this regression has weights in it to make the sample representing for the entire US-population. The weights, however, are survey-weights without regard to the state the individual lives in. As far as I understand, for a correct regression model, my data would need to have weights for the individual probability to be drawn into the sample at state-level. Is that correct?

What would you recommend me to so? Should I still use the weights (even though they concern the total probability to be drawn into the sample, not the probability for the respective state) or should I better not use weighting at all?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Have you run your model with and without weights? Do the results differ?

Comment: @ErikRuzek Yes, they actually differ quite a lot. I am running five interactions and in both models one of the terms is significantly positive, but it's a different one for each model. So my results seem to depend on the weights, but none of the weights are the correct ones to use.

Comment: What software and package are you using for these analyses?